# Shutter screenshot application is broken since upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute Hippo

Tags: upgrade, screenshot, shutter

Since upgrading to 21.04, the Shutter screenshot tool stopped working.
I installed it from the PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu, it is at `Version 0.95, Rev.1450`

Let's say, I start in this configuration:
[image: Starting setup]

When I now try to screenshot a selection, instead of showing the screen contents, it tiles it's own window content:
[image: Tiled window content]

I would assume this has something to do with permissions, since the `Window` dropdown list is empty. Trying to capture the whole desktop yields an error message `Keyboard could not be grabbed.`

I already tried re-installing it via `apt purge`. There are no matching issues on Shutter's Github page.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: After upgrading from 20.04 lts to 21.04 all I see are black screens on dual monitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutter support pointed me to the root cause:

[Ubuntu 21.04 switched to wayland (again)](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-use-wayland/), and shutter does not support wayland (yet).

See Shutter [Github issue](https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/issues/187) for it.

**Workaround** as pointed out by @N0rbert

1. Log out of Ubuntu
2. Select your user account
3. Click on the gear wheel (lower right of screen) and select `Ubuntu on Xorg`
4. Login again

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be caused by Wayland session.

You have to logout and then login back to *Ubuntu on Xorg*.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to remove shutter. Then, change the source of your install as the PPA is not the official one.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install shutter
```

References :
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/official-shutter-screenshot-tool.html

Comment: Thank you for the update, I switched to the new PPA and updated to `v0.99 Rev.1591`. Am I correct that this still won't work with wayland? Reading the discussion on github looks like it's still an issue

Comment: @tannerli It says on the page "It's important to note that Shutter does not support Wayland yet!"