# Ubuntu 22.04. Flameshot not working

Tags: 22.04

Just upgraded to 22.04 from 21.10. Flameshot not working. I click on the Flameshot icon and nothing happens. How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe, something in the system logs can help you find the root cause for the issue. Please, have a look at `/var/log/syslog`, and search it for "flameshot"

Comment: Could it be that you do see a tray icon appear?
Because that is what happens when I press the icon from the launcher menu.
Try to run `flameshot gui` from a terminal and see what happens.
Also see:
https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot#usage

Comment: The workaround is to use Ubuntu on Xorg as per this reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344236/shutter-screenshot-application-is-broken-since-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-h

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland? Could be a Wayland issue.

Comment: @MartinZeltin It's been working and I'm using Wayland. I think an update fixed it about 8 months ago.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly do not install flameshot from snapstore, install it using apt.

- Go to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- Remove the comment on `#WaylandEnable=false`

Your `custom.conf` file should be like this:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

Save `custom.conf` file and restart your machine

Comment: This seems also solve the issue of `parcellite`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the issue from the OP but I came here having the same symptoms and this was the solution:

When you install Flameshot from the software center you get only one icon in Gnome. If you click this button nothing happens. Except for a tray icon that probably goes unnoticed to most users (like me).

From the [Flameshot documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot#usage):

> [...] will launch a running instance of the program in background without taking actions [...]

To actually take a screenshot you would have to run `flameshot gui` but there is no icon for that.

#### Take screenshot to test

To test the functionality you have two options:

1. Right click the launcher icon, in the context menu you should have the option to 'Take screenshot'
2. Run `flameshot gui` from a terminal or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and copy paste/type the command there.

You should get a security prompt by Gnome, asking if you are OK to share the entire screen(shot) to the application (Flameshot). You click 'share' and now Flameshot opens as you know it. (At the time of writing you [cannot disable](https://flameshot.org/docs/guide/wayland-help/#gnome) this security step)

#### Make a keyboard shortcut

Now to get a more convenient way to start Flameshot you can add a keyboard shortcut to the command `flameshot gui`. Explained [here on the GitHub page of Flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot#on-ubuntu-tested-on-1804-2004-2204). For example you can bind this command to the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> button.

#### Customise the default launcher

Alternatively you could edit the default Flameshot launcher to take the screenshot immediately when clicking the icon.

First copy the *.desktop file to your home directory so it will persist even when the system udpates or whatever:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/org.flameshot.Flameshot.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then edit the copy somehow:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/org.flameshot.Flameshot.desktop
```

Find the (first) line that says:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/flameshot gui --delay 500
```

And append it like this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/flameshot gui --delay 500
```

Comment: OP here. Using Ubuntu 22.04. Flameshot is installed. Here's what happens: * I go to the Gnome "search" screen, type in "flame", the large Flameshot icon appears, I click on it and a very small Flameshot icon appears in my dock, I click on the tiny Flameshot icon and a menu appears, one of the menu items is "Take a Screenshot"", I click on this and nothing happens. How to fix this? Thanks. PS: I do a Ubuntu software update everyday. PS: Flameshot worked fine in 21.10, I didn't have to do anything special for it to work great.

Comment: What happens when you run `flameshot gui` from the command line?

Comment: Here's what hppens:

advait@advait-Bravo-15-A4DDR:~$ flameshot gui
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
.
Then nothing more happens and I have to hit ctrl-c to kill the process. I'm using Wayland. I'll wait til the Flameshot bugs are fixed and use Gnome Screenshot in the meantime. I'm not willing to run X11.

Answer (score 2):

OP here. Issue Resolved. It's working. The solution is I take a screenshot with Flameshot and then a dialog box appears with the option to share the screenshot with Flameshot. I do this and then I can edit the screenshot using the very nice Flameshot tools and UI. Kind of a weird and convoluted process, but it works in Wayland. I found this solution months ago but only today I got a reminder email about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to x.org at login.

At login, as you clock in the password field, a small gear icon appears at the bottom right of the login screen. Click it and select xorg.

Before doing that, it is worth checking if you have xorg installed entering `dpkg --list | grep xorg` in terminal

If you don't have it, you can install it with `sudo apt install xorg openbox`

Logout, login again (selecting xorg in the login screen) and it should work.

(At least it did for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I did the update this week. There were initial hickups.

- As I usually do, I changed the keyboard binding for "Print" to call `flameshot gui` instead of the default screenshot tool (I disabled that hotkey before I added a custom binding for Flameshot).
- It worked, but I would have to take a screenshot first, then "Share" it with Flameshot, and only then could I use Flameshot like before, like normal.
- Although it was a different issue, maybe, **it disappeared for me, yesterday or so. With a recent update, I presume.** Now I just press print, then Flameshot launches directly, like it used to in the past.

**Could you run all updates, then re-check if it's working for you then?**

Also, could you launch Flameshot once by hand, then check your settings? E.g. "launch at startup" must be enabled, or it won't react to hotkeys, if I remember correctly.

If you give more details, I'll gladly provide more detailed information (like, ironically, screenshots).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP here. I just did all the updates and re-installed Flameshot. Still not working. I'll check again after some time and hope that the devs are working on this.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04 it opens, but the clipboard copying doesn't work at all for me

Comment: Sorry then, I don't think I have had the same kind of problem then, and won't be able to help. And, as the bot pointed out, I should not have answered then. :(